# Are there a finite number of elementary zero-sum walks in a signed finite directed graph?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs, signed-graphs

Let $G=(V,E,w)$ be a signed directed graph where every vertex $v\in V$ has out-degree $2$, and every directed edge $e\in E$ has sign $w(e)\in\{-1, +1\}$.

A walk $z = (v_1, e_1, v_2, e_2, \ldots, v_{k-1}, e_{k-1}, v_k)$ in $G$ is an alternating sequence of vertices and directed edges where $e_i=(v_i, v_{i+1})$ for $i=1, \ldots, k-1$. Let us designate the walk $z$ as **elementary** if the following two conditions hold:

1. $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} w(e_i)=0$.
2. For all $1 \leqslant k' < k-1$, the value of $\sum_{i=1}^{k'} w(e_i)$ is non-zero.

Let $W(G)$ be the set of all elementary walks in $G$.

I am looking to prove (or disprove by counterexample) the statement: If $G$ is finite, then $|W(G)|$ is finite.

If anyone has an intuition for this type of problem or has seen results that seem related to this, I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: 1->2, 2->1, 1->3 positive, 3->4, 4->3 negative?

Comment: A variation of this (which ensures the out-degree 2 condition) works as a counterexample @JBL. Thank you! The problem arose while thinking about the finite state machine of a deterministic Turing machine; the +1 and -1 labels represented "move the tape head left" and "move the tape head right" operations. Elementary paths correspond to returning to a previous position on the tape.

Answer (score 1):

My example in comments is built on the following principle: if the graph contains a positive cycle and a negative cycle and a path between them, you can go around the positive cycle as many times as you like before walking over to the negative cycle and moving back to 0.  The simplest (loopless) way to do that is with the edges
$$ 
\{ a \overset{+}{\to} b, b \overset{+}{\to} a, a \overset{+}{\to} c, c \overset{-}{\to} d, d \overset{-}{\to} c\} \cup \{b \to ??, c \to ??, d \to ??\}, 
$$
where the last three are just there to make the degree condition work and their signs and termini don't matter.

In fact there is a simpler way to do it, namely, by having a cycle of net weight 0 with a positive path into it and a negative path out.  This can be achieved with just three vertices:
$$
\{
a \overset{+}{\to} b, \quad b \overset{+}{\to} c, c \overset{-}{\to} b, \quad b \overset{-}{\to} a\} \cup \{ a \to c, c \to a\},
$$
where again the last two edges are there just to make the degree conditions work.

Comment: Thank you @JBL, for a very clear and thoughtful response. I am taking your phrase "positive cycle" to mean "net" positive cycle. In light of your observations, it seems that "most graphs" would have an infinite $|W(G)|$.

Comment: @BilalKhan Yes, a net positive cycle.  I am not sure about "most graphs" (if that means we restrict to the family of directed graphs with all vertices of out-degree 2) just because it's not completely clear to me that most graphs in this family have cycles.  (I haven't thought hard about it, maybe it's easy to see that they do.  If the average number of cycles grows with the number of vertices in this class, then I would expect you're right and most graphs in the family should have infinite $|W(G)|$.)